# UTF-8: � or <92>

Tags: php, vim, utf-8

I don't know if this helps, but I'm using phpstorm to edit a file created in vim. In vim, the character shows up as <92>. In PHPStorm, it's: �. I want to replace � with a correct version of the character. This is code that's looking for curly quotes, I think:

```
$contact->notes = preg_replace( "/<92>/", "'", $contact->notes );
```

I'm open to hearing about a full solution (iconv, etc), but would also like a simple fix if that's available. (This code is getting migrated and I just want to push my changes.)

Comment: I've not used VIM but I bet that <92> means byte 0x92 which is not  valid in UTF8 (or maybe byte 2-6) - check encodingd here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: BTW - better paste at least fragment of the file as hex bytes

Comment: How do I paste as hex? I'll google it, but if you know, please share.

Comment: Fix your title please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The byte `0x92` encodes a "curly quote" in the [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character encoding. You can convert text in this encoding to UTF-8 for example with `iconv`:

```
$text_utf8 = iconv("cp1252", "utf-8", $text_orig);
```

What that will do is encode the curly quote in UTF-8. If your output device (web browser?) is not configured to use UTF-8 you may see mangled characters. To avoid that you can just convert everything to ASCII:

```
$text_ascii = iconv("cp1252", "ascii//translit", $text_orig);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the character and just pasted it in: ’